# how to configure postgresql / pgbouncer using unix sockets?

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

cannot make simplest `pgbouncer / postgresql` combo work using default unix sockets.

logged in as `foo`, with an existent database (created by `foo`) `bar`. these work fine:

```
$ psql bar
$ psql -U foo bar
$ psql -U foo --password bar
```

in `/etc/pgbouncer/userlist.txt`:

```
"foo" "foo"
```

in `/etc/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.ini`:

```
[databases]
mydb =

[pgbouncer]
unix_socket_dir = /var/run/postgresql
auth_type = trust
auth_file = /etc/pgbouncer/userlist.txt
```

when I try to login with `psql -p 6432 mydb` or with `psql -p 6432 mydb --password`, after entering password, I get

```
psql: ERROR:  Peer authentication failed for user "foo"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

log in to psql with password anr run "show hba_file;"
the vi the pg_hba.conf file - change "local" section to trust for user foo...

or

just before running pgbouncer run export PGPASSWORD='whatever_password_is',

or

create a .pgpass file with saved password...